# Modify Cordova SQLite Plugin

Tags: javascript, ios, sqlite, cordova, encryption

Being a total newbie at Cordova I wonder how I should proceed in order to modify the SQLite Plugin (https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin/) and use the modified version in my app.

I need to encrypt sensitive data before actually saving it to the DB, and I believe it would be harder for a cracker to know how is the data actually being encrypted by doing such encryption with native code (probably spreading through several classes/files) instead of doing it in javascript.

I guess another option would be to use the unmodified SQLite plugin and having some native classes to do the encryption before handling the data to the DB plugin. I am only targeting iOS, but still I have no clear idea on how to properly mix the native code with the javascript one. Should I create a plugin? Is it enough if I create a native class with a javacript wrapper? How to create an instance of such class from the javascript code? I am so confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to be gained by hiding "how" the data is encrypted, that is the method, encryption type, key size or iv. One does not improve encryption by hiding how it is done.

The security is in a good encryption key, securing the key and using the encryption primitives in a secure manner. For starters choose AES in CBC mode with a good iv. Do not use a password as the key, either use a random bit-string or run a password through PBKDF2 to generate the key.

One challenge with encryption in javascript is protecting the key, in a native app it can be kept in the Keychain.

If you are serious about the security get a cryptographic domain expert to create the secure portion of the code or at a minimum to review the methods and code.

Comment: Thanks. I was indeed mainly thinking about how to secure the key, like having different portions in several files but your suggestions sound much better. I have a question, how would the random key work? Let the app generate it and then store it in the keychain? In the case I would like to communicate with the server sending the data encrypted (besides using HTTPS) would this approach work or this is only useful for local data? I mean, I can't figure out how the server would be able to decrypt data encrypted with a random key.

Comment: These are two seperate uses. For encryption on the device yes, generate a random key, save it in the Keychain. When you need to encrypt opr decrypt get the key from the Keychain an use it. This is purely for local usage.

Comment: For communicating with the server there are two issues: 1. Authentication to the server. 2. Transferring the data securely. Why do you not want to use HTTPS? If you use your own encryption there is a key sharing problem to be resolved, HTTPS solves this problem.

Comment: Thanks again. I didn't mean I don't want to use HTTPS but to actually encrypt the data before it is sent and encrypted via HTTPS. I was thinking about extra security against man in the middle attacks.